# Looking for partial information with DCOUNTA()

Tags: google-sheets

I have a database (DatosBanderas) that, among other things, has information on the composition of the local government in a set of municipalities. The issue is that there are quite a few municipalities governed by a coalition of several parties. The composition of the local government is stored in a field named "Gobierno" and is of the form "Party 1 + Party 2 + ... + Party n." Of course, it is also posible for only one party to be in the municipal government, in which case it's just "Party i." I'm trying to count the number of municipalities in which each political party governs. To that effect, I'm using

```
 counta(DatosBanderas;"MUNICIPIO";{not(iserror(find("Party j";"Gobierno")));"true"})
```

("MUNICIPIO" is just the name of the municipiality). I do get a numerical output, but it's an impossibly high number (total number of municipalities is 947, the formula returns 19904, and for "Party j" I was expecting 3).

**Edit** I've found an obvious mistake, I should use `DCOUNTA()` rather than `COUNTA()`. However, the formula still returns a wrong answer, 0. Can formulas be used on fields of the database (as I'm trying to do here)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I'm trying to count the number of municipalities in which each political party governs.*

You have asked for a solution using dcounta. It's easy to create a count for a specific party. It's possible to convert this to create a count for *each* party though there are multiple formula involved.

As an alternative, this answer provides a count by party in a single formula. We'll assume that the data is in Columns A, B and C.

Use this formula to create a list of unique parties and the count of the number of times they are in government.

`=query({flatten(arrayformula(trim(split(substitute(query({A3:C};"select Col3 where Col1 !=''";0);"+";",");",";true;true))))};"select Col1, count(Col1) where Col1 != '' group by Col1 order by count(Col1) desc label Col1 'Party'"; 0)`

---

**SAMPLE**

[image: query screenshot]

---

**LOGIC**

- `query({A3:C};"select Col3 where Col1 !=''";0)` - initial query to exclude blank rows
- `substitute(<<QUERY>>;",";true;true)` - substitutes `,` for `+`
- `split(<<substitute>>;",";true;true))` - splits the data into columns
- `trim(<<split>>)` - cleans up any left over spaces
- `arrayformula(<<trim>>)` - applies the formula to every row of data
- `flatten(<<arrayformula>>)` - converts the data from multiple rows/columns to a single column list
- `query({<<flatten>>};"select Col1, count(Col1) where Col1 != '' group by Col1 order by count(Col1) desc label Col1 'Party'"; 0)` - excludes blank rows, counts the instances and groups by party name

Answer (score 1):

I've found a simple solution using `DCOUNTA()`: just use wildcards

```
=DCOUNTA(DatosBanderas;"MUNICIPIO";{"Gobierno";"*Party 1*"})
```

Comment: I'm pleased that you found this. This is the formula that I had in mind when I said _ It's easy to create a count for a specific party._ The problem is that the party name must be hard coded into the formula. Another option is to enter the party name in a cell and reference that cell in the formula. Such as `=DCOUNTA(DatosBanderas;"MUNICIPIO";{"Gobierno";"*"&I1&"*"})` where Cell#I1 contains `Party 3`. If you have a list of all the parties, you could easily create the count just by copying this formula down adjacent to a column of party names.

Comment: Yes, thats what I did (using ```CONCATENATE()``` rather than the simpler ```&```). Your answer, though, proved very handy in identifying coding errors in the parties names

Comment: AAMOI, did you already have a list of the various “parties”? I ask because unless one is “required” to use DCOUNTA, it is not the approach that would immediately spring to mind.

Comment: @Tedinoz, yes I had the list. It's not that I was _requiered_ to use ```DCOUNTA()``` it's just that my knowledge of sheets is limited I could have never dreamed of writting the formula you proposed.